# CSS Background Image Not Displaying over the other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Actually, I have to place the background image over the other, like this:

**Expected Output:**
[image]

I added the 1st background image to the `body` and the other one as background to the `inner-body`-class. The `body` background image is displayed properly, but the second background-image is not displayed at all.

Check the inspect element code here attached below:

**woking body image**(code):
[image]

**2nd image "inner-body" image not showing**(code):
[image]

But if I specify a height for `inner-body` (e.g. 600px) the image is shown, but it is not the right way, because in responsive mode it will be bad.

What am I doing wrong?

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: url("bg-image1.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .inner-body {
            background: url("bg-image2.jpg");
            background-size: auto;
            /*height: 687px;*/
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-body">
            <div class="form-body"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide link or snippet

Comment: Logesh can you share your code?

Comment: Do not post the code into the comments, but instead edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

Give this style to html, body, and container:

### CSS

```
html, body, .container {
   min-height: 100%;
}

body {
   padding: 200px;
}

.inner-body {
   max-height:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is no content inside your inner-body div, you must add some content inside it then it will take auto height, or you must give height to that div. There is no other way i think.